# can public contextmenu test still be done?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

Part of the Google Espresso code is the Menutest. You can find it [Espresso menutest](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/espresso/libtests/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/sample/MenuTest.java?r=6dc2d307927f6afc497a1fb0292f42d8e725d227).

In this test you will see:

```
public void testContextMenu() {
    onView(withText(R.string.context_item_2_text)).check(doesNotExist());
    onView(withId(R.id.text_context_menu)).perform(longClick());
    onView(withText(R.string.context_item_2_text)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.text_menu_result)).check(matches(withText(R.string.context_item_2_text)));
}
```

In this test you see that the contextmenu is started via a longClick. When I try to reproduce this test, the longClick() is not given via the Eclipse/Espresso 1.1 jar.

Do you have a valid Espresso context menu test? Please let me know. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Yashodhan:

Just use this import:

```
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.action.ViewActions.longClick;
```

Yes, and it works! And the tests all went well.